# "before it" or "before of it"?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

Should I use the preposition "of" in the following context before the word "before" (or in the pronoun "it" after "before")?

> "The word "pillow" is a countable noun and therefore you should put an
>   article before (**of**) it."

Now I understand that I have 3 choices:

> 1) ...therefore you should put an article before."
>
> 2) ...therefore you should put an article before **it**."
>
> 3) ...therefore you should put an article before **of it**."

What is the correct choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is choice 2:

> ..therefore you should put an article before it.

However, you could also say:

> ..therefore you should put an article in front **of** it.

We use “of” with “in front”, but not with “before”.

Comment: Many times I hear people who end a sentence with the word "before", van you write when should it be like that, if any? (I mean if it's not a mistake).

Comment: @subtle_sibling Before can end a sentence when it means _before the current time_. As in, _I've heard that before (now)_ or _He didn't hear anything he hadn't heard before (then)._